Showing that $f(x)= \frac{2x^2+3x+1}{2x-1} $ is injective on $2≤x<3$
Showing that $$f(x)= \frac{2x^2+3x+1}{2x-1} $$ is injective on $2≤x<3$
I am currently reading through Bartle's Intro to Real Analysis. On page 34, an exercise asks you to find a constant $M$ such that the absolute value of $f(x)$ is less than $M$. My idea was to show that $f(x)$ is increasing on the interval and choosing $M$ as the supremum of it. And for the monotonicity of $f(x)$, I recalled a theorem that says that if $f(x)$ is injective and has the IVT property (it is a Darboux function), then $f(x)$ is monotonic.
I know from the graphical representation of $f(x)$ that it is injective, but despite my efforts, I am not able to prove it with the usual method of supposing that $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$.
Edit: I know that applying the derivative quickly solves the problem. I focus on proving the injectivity, which should be very simple, but I'm stuck. Besides, continuity and derivatives are much later introduced. Moreover, Bartle's solution involves triangle inequality without any mention of growing functions.

The derivative is never $0$ in that region.

Check the derivative and use Lagrange's mean value theorem.

I know that derivatives solve the problem, but injectivity is what sparked my curiosity on the excercise

Suppose $f(x) = f(y)$. Using Hanno's decomposition,
$$x + 2 + \frac{3}{2x - 1} = y + 2 + \frac{3}{2y - 1}.$$
Equivalently,
$$x - y = \frac{3}{2y - 1} - \frac{3}{2x - 1} = 3\frac{2x - 1 - (2y - 1)}{(2x - 1)(2y - 1)} = 6\frac{x - y}{(2x - 1)(2y - 1)}.$$
If $x = y$, we are done. Otherwise,
$$1 = \frac{6}{(2x - 1)(2y - 1)} \implies (2x - 1)(2y - 1) = 6.$$
But, since $x, y \ge 2$, we have $2x - 1, 2y - 1 \ge 3$, so $6 = (2x - 1)(2y - 1) \ge 9$, which is a contradiction. Thus, $x = y$ is the only possibility, and $f(x)$ is injective for $x \ge 2$ (or $x \ge \frac{1+\sqrt{6}}{2}$ for that matter).

The usual (direct!) method to prove the monotonicity was already indicated in the comments and the first answer.
However, yours (relying on a sophisticated theorem) is also possible, since you can prove that $f$ is injective like you intended to (on $[2,3)$ and even on $[a,\infty)$, where
$a:=\frac{1+\sqrt6}2\approx1.7$):
Assume $y=x+\delta\ge x\ge a$ and $f(x)=f(y)$. Then,
$$0=(2y^2+3y+1)(2x-1)-(2x^2+3x+1)(2y-1)$$
$$=(y-x)(4xy-5-2(x+y))$$
$$=\delta((2x-1)^2-6+\delta(4x-2))$$
$$\ge\delta^2(4a-2)\ge4\delta^2$$
hence $\delta=0$, i.e. $y=x$.
Note that this calculation also proves the (strict) monotonicity, even more directly than the usual method: if $y=x+\delta\color{red}>x\ge a$ then
$$(2x-1)(2y-1)(f(y)-f(x))\ge4\delta^2>0$$ hence $f(y)>f(x)$.

The partial fraction decomposition yields
$$f(x)= \frac{2x^2+3x+1}{2x-1} = x+2+\frac3{2x-1}\,,$$
then
$$f'(x)=1-\frac6{(2x-1)^2}\:\stackrel{!}{>}\:0
\;\iff\; x>\frac{\sqrt 6 +1}2\approx 1.72\;\vee\;x<\frac{-\sqrt 6 +1}2\approx -0.72$$
hence the derivative is strictly positive in the interval $[2,3]$.

To show that the function $f(x)=\frac{2x^2+3x+1}{2x-1}$ is injective on the interval $2\leq x<3$ or $[2,3)$, we need to prove that for any $a,b\in[2,3),\ f(a)=f(b)\implies a=b$.
Let's assume $f(a)=f(b)$ for $a,b\in[2,3)$. Using algebraic manipulation,
$$\frac{2a^2+3a+1}{2a-1}=\frac{2b^2+3b+1}{2b-1}\implies(a-b)\left[2a(2b-1)-(2b+5)\right]=0\tag{1}$$
Now, we have either $a=b$ or $a=\frac{2b+5}{2(2b-1)}$. But $2\leq a=\frac{2b+5}{2(2b-1)}<3\implies\frac{11}{10}<b\leq\frac32$ which is not true for $a,b\in[2,3)$. So, for any $a,b\in[2,3)$, $f(a)=f(b)\implies a=b$. Hence, the given function $f(x)$ is injective on $2\leq x<3$. $\textbf{Q.E.D.}$

$\frac {2x^2 + 3x+1}{2x-1}= \frac {2x^2 - x + 4x -2 + 3}{2x-1}= x+2 +\frac {3}{2x-1}$
If $x < y$ and $y = x+t; t>0$ then
$f(y)=f(x+t) = (x+2) + t + \frac 3{2(x+t)-1}$.
$= (x+2) + \frac 3{2x-1} + [t +\frac 3{2(x+t)-1}-\frac 3{2x+1}]$
We just have to show $[t +\frac 3{2(x+t)-1}-\frac 3{2x-1}]\ne 0$
$t+ \frac 3{2(x+t)-1}-\frac 3{2x-1} = $
$t + \frac {3[(2x-1) - (2x-1+2t)}{(2x -1+2t)(2x-1)}=$
$t - \frac {6t}{(2x -1+2t)(2x-1)}>$
$t -\frac {6t}{(2x-1)(2x-1)}\ge $
$t-\frac {6t}{(2\cdot 3-1)(2\cdot 3-1)}=t-\frac {6t}{25}=\frac {19}{25} t > 0$.
So $x< y \implies f(x) < f(y)$ so is $f$ injective and monotonically increasing.
